# 3.1 post formats and specific categories/custom taxonomies

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, post-formats

Is there a way to have a specific custom taxonomy for new 3.1 post formats?

Let's say for example we want to categorize the "gallery" post format with two categories —only available for those kind of posts— as in "portfolio" and "others". How can we do that? Going even further how can we sub-categorize those with a bunch of tags only available for those custom posts (as for example "people", "landscape", "cityscape", etc.)?

Is it better to switch to custom post types + custom taxonomies to do this?

Answer (score 1):

"Post Format" is simply a custom taxonomy, and it is - by design - not extensible.

I would recommend just implementing this procedurally, by only using specific tags with specific Post Formats.

**EDIT**

I would start with the Codex entry on [Post Formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats).

Here's a little primer I wrote on [using Post Formats as a taxonomy](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/01/11/using-wordpress-post-formats-as-a-taxonomy/).

As for tutorials for implementing Post Formats, there are several. Just try a [Google search for "WordPress Post Formats"](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=emsp&cp=18&gs_id=67&xhr=t&q=wordpress+post+formats).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think there's something I'm not grasping though. How can tags be specific to post formats if they're not extensible custom taxonomies?

Comment: Tags *can't* be specific to another taxonomy (Categories, Post Formats, or any other, custom taxonomy); that's why I said that you'd have to implement it *procedurally* (as in: controlled by your own actions, as opposed to WordPress controlling it).

Comment: ok thanks for the additional info. I've appreciated. May you also be so kind to give me some link to any tutorial about this matter?